# What version of PUBG Mobile is on playstore, Timi or Lightspeed?

Tags: version-differences, pubg-battlegrounds, mobile

Basically my question is that what's the difference between timi and lightspeed version of PUBG Mobile and what version is on playstore. As I see only one version and that is by tencent games. So what i'm playing actually, tencent PUBG or timi or lightspeed.

Comment: lightspeed, ofcourse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Releases

The **Timi** version of PUGB was released on the Chinese App Store first for both iOS and Android devices (it has not yet been released elsewhere).

> However, it will first roll out in China before it becomes available to the rest of the world.

The **Lightspeed & Quantum** version of PUGB is released over the world for both iOS and Android devices.

So **you are playing the Lightspeed version** of the game.

[*(source)*](https://www.iphonefirmware.com/pubg-mobile-timi-studio-vs-lightspeed-quantum-studio-versions-whats-the-difference/)

---

## Differences

The differences between the 2 versions:

> The Army Attack release by Timi Studio has a distinct focus on Land,
>   Sea, and Air Battles. This is fundamentally different from the PC
>   version meaning that there has been some artistic license afforded to
>   the company in order to offer something slightly different and
>   dynamic, but still under the PUBG brand.
>
> For the purists, which are those individuals who loved the original PC
>   game and just essentially wanted a mobile version, there is the
>   Exhilarating Battlefield version by Lightspeed & Quantum Studio. This
>   is basically the like-for-like attempt to port the original game to
>   iOS and Android mobile devices and trying to preserve the original
>   look and feel of the original title.

[*(source)*](https://www.iphonefirmware.com/pubg-mobile-timi-studio-vs-lightspeed-quantum-studio-versions-whats-the-difference/)

Similarities between the 2 versions:

> Industry analyst Daniel Ahmad said that both games are made using
>   Epic's Unreal Engine 4.

[*(source)*](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/playerunknowns-battlegrounds-newsupdates-two-new-mobile-games-announced/120357.htm)